# ORA-01841 Passing Data Between tables without convert dates. Oracle SQL

Tags: database, oracle, sql-insert

I am getting this error when I am trying move data from one table to another.

> Informe de error - ORA-01841: el valor (completo) del año debe estar
> entre -4713 y +9999, y no debe ser igual a 0

Tables are very similar (only one field of difference) and have content. I dont know why I am getting this error because I am not working with date in char formats, only passing data between tables.

I was testing a little and the problematic field is **AFFE_DA_END**

[image: Tables structure]

This is my SQL:

```
INSERT INTO CETPS_AFFECTATION ( 
    AFFE_ID_AFFECTATION, 
    AFFE_DA_END, 
    AUDI_TI_CREATION, 
    AFFE_IN_STATE, 
    AFFE_DA_CREATE, 
    USER_ID_CREATOR_PARTY, 
    AFFE_IN_IS_COMPENSABLE, 
    PROB_ID_SERVICE_PROBLEM, 
    PROB_ID_RESOURCE_TROUBLE, 
    SPAF_ID_SUPERAFFECTATION, 
    USER_ID_UPDATER_PARTY, 
    AUDI_TI_UPDATE 
)                
SELECT 
    AFFE_ID_AFFECTATION, 
    AFFE_DA_END, 
    AUDI_TI_CREATION, 
    AFFE_IN_STATE, 
    AFFE_DA_CREATE, 
    USER_ID_CREATOR_PARTY, 
    AFFE_IN_IS_COMPENSABLE, 
    PROB_ID_SERVICE_PROBLEM, 
    PROB_ID_RESOURCE_TROUBLE, 
    SPAF_ID_SUPERAFFECTATION, 
    USER_ID_UPDATER_PARTY, 
    AUDI_TI_UPDATE  
FROM CETPP_AFFECTATION  
WHERE 
    AFFE_ID_AFFECTATION = 12816009148666938884425181441241238906;
```

This "Select clause" returns content
[image]

Comment: Can you post the EXPLAIN PLAN for the INSERT statement? Do you see any implicit data type conversion in it?

Comment: Can you also include the full error message/stack you get (preferably in English)? I'm wondering if the target table has a trigger that is causing the problem, because that is doing an implicit conversion.